# Compare NSObjects ignoring pointers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsobject

I have a model class (subclass of `NSObject`) which I am storing in 2 mutable arrays. In one array I am storing the objects directly and in the other I am storing a copy of it using `[myObject copy]`. I would like to compare these 2 arrays by ignoring the pointers i.e. the address where they are stored. If the objects match, it should return `YES`.

I tried using `isEqualToArray` but it doesnt work for `NSObject` subclass since it compares the pointers as well.

Suggestions or any work around for this is appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that you got the correct answer already to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109077/mutable-array-comparison-for-copied-objects.

Comment: even many answers are already there, just google.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override two methods in your subclass of NSObject:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
- (NSUInteger)hash
```

Add the logic you want to isEqual method, for example:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    MyObject *obj = (MyObject*)object;
    if ([self.name isEqualToString obj.name])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

There are plenty of examples online. After that you can cal isEqual to compare your object.
Hope this help.

Comment: Overriding those methods reminds me of Java. I wonder if they have any indirect historical connection between the both languages in this regard.